# How to find probability of path in a directed graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, weighted

I have a **directed weighted** graph G=(V,E).

In this graph the weight of edge(v[i],v[j]) is the count of transition between v[i] and v[j].

I am trying to determine the best way to accomplish task: **how to find the probability P of path from node A to node B**

All weights are positive integers.

For example,

```
weight(A,B)=count of transition from A to B
weight(B,C)=count of transition from B to C
weight(B,D)=count of transition from B to D
weight(D,C)=count of transition from D to C
```

And we have several paths:

```
A->B->C 
A->B->D->C
```

So, how to calculate probability P of these paths and choose the best one?

Comment: It's not clear where probabilities are supposed to come from here. What do you mean by "count of transition"? And what makes one path the best? You haven't given us a clear enough problem statement for us to answer the question.

Comment: @user2357112 For example, the count of transition - the number of transitions from A to the place B . The best path is a path with the most probability. My attempt to solve this: P=the sum of weights of the edges belonging to this path. But I have a problem that the path with the greatest length will have the greatest probability, but It is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be solved by reducing the problem to [shortest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem), assuming we are indeed discussing probabilities (that means, each weight is in range `[0,1]`).

Let the graph be `G=(V,E)`, and the probability between two vertices denoted as `w(u,v)`.

Define:
w'(u,v) = -log(w(u,v))

The shortest path from some node `s` to some node `t` is then the shortest path in the graph when using `w'` as weight function. You can find the shortest path using [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) or [Bellman-Ford algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm)

Proof:

For a path `v1->v2->...->vn`, its probability is `w(v1,v2) * w(v2,v3) * ... * w(vn-1,vn)`.

When using `w'` as the weight, the cost of this path when using any shortest path algorithm is:

```
d(v1,vn) = w'(v1,v2) + w'(v2,v3) + ... + w'(vn-1,vn) = 
d(v1,vn) = -log(w(v1,v2)) + -log(w(v2,v3) + ... + -log(w(vn-1,vn)) = 
d(v1,vn) = -1* [ log(w(v1,v2)) + log(w(v2,v3)) + ... + log(w(vn-1,vn)) =
d(v1,vn) = -1* log(w(v1,v2) * w(v2,v3) * ... * w(vn-1,vn))
```

This obviously applies also for the minimal path found from `s` to `t`.

This means that this path have minimal value of:

```
s(s,t) = -1* log(w(s,v2) * w(v2,v3) * ... * w(vn-1,t))
```

And since log is monotonic function, it is also minimal value of `-1 * w(s,v2) * w(v2,v3) * ... * w(vn-1,t)`, which is the maximal value of `w(s,v2) * w(v2,v3) * ... * w(vn-1,t)`, and that's exactly the probability.

Comment: This looks quite sophisticated. I suggest you to use array notation v[i] instead of vi (and actually instead of v_i what is in the OP).  I suggest to add a reference to the "logarithmic"-trick.  I suggest to remove the overexplanatory lines because it makes the answer look *more difficult than it actually is*. Also, I guess you assume some kind of independence, which should be made explicit.

Comment: @amit w'(u,v) value in range([0;1]) ? If I have w(u,v) = count of transitions from node u to node v, how to get w'(u,v)?

Comment: @Andrei `-log(count of transitions from node u to node v)`, as it states for general `w(.,.)`.

Comment: @amit I have a misunderstanding, how now the weight will be in [0;1] ?

Comment: @Andrei Apologies, 3 weeks passed since the answer was given an your question. You are right, in this case you need to normalize it somehow to be in `[0,1]`. One way to do so will be to define `w(u,v) = #transitions from u to v / #transition from u to any node`, or any other normalization you can think of. Without having [0,1] range, this is a significantly harder problem and if I remember correctly is equivalent to Longest Path Problem (which is NP-Complete).